# shmat returns segmentation falut with errno=13(EACCES)

Tags: c, linux, posix

I just want test shmget() and shmat() , but something seems wrong. :(

shmget() works well but shmat() causes segmentation fault.

this is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    key_t key=98;/* yes, just 98 for test */
    int shid;
    char *str=NULL;
    shid = shmget(key, 4096, IPC_CREAT);
    printf("shid:%d\n",shid);
    str=(char*)shmat(shid,NULL,0);
    printf("str:%d\n",(int)str);
    printf("errno:%d\n", errno);
    str[0] = 'h';
    str[1] = '\0';

    return 0;
}
```

this is the output:

```
shid:28246036
str:-1
errno:13
zsh: segmentation fault  ./t1
```

thx :D

Comment: As you removed the cause for the segmentation violation from the source snippet, you should also remove the various other references to it from your posting. Moreover it has never been the call to `shmat()` which caused the segmentation violation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must define `_SVID_SOURCE` or `_XOPEN_SOURCE` at the very begin

```
#define _SVID_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
...
```

Create `key` using `ftok()`

```
key_t key= ftok("demo.c", 'R');
```

It returns `errno 13` because you don't set PERMS:

```
shid = shmget(key, 4096, IPC_CREAT);
```

must be

```
shid = shmget(key, 4096, 0777 | IPC_CREAT);
```